# Running Spartacus Storefront in IE11 returning classList error even though we have required polyfills

Tags: spartacus-storefront

We are evaluating Spartacus for our B2B eCommerce site re-platform. One of the main requirement is to support IE11 (MUST).  As per Spartacus documentation, Angular itself supports IE11 with polyfills and so Spartacus should work in IE11 without Spartacus styles (variable css).

We have tried to pollyfill OOTB Spartacus (3.1 & 3.2 in SSR mode & non SSR) and it is loading the pages & functionality but we are getting classList error in web console. Even though we have required polyfills. Below are the polyfills that we have installed & configured :

- classlist.js
- web-animation.js
- core-js
- and also target compilation is es5.

[IE11 -Spartacus 3.1 & 3.2 classList error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dpg2v.png)

***Any help to resolve this classLIST error would be helpful.***

So,  does anyone made Spartacus work in IE11  with your own stylesheets ?

Comment: I have stated issue & question as I stated in the post. We are getting an error to make the Spartacus work in IE11 and the corresponding pollyfill configuration & error screenshot has been shared. Please do let me know if i need to be more clear than that and need any other information. And also, in general asking Spartacus forum, that anyone made the spartacus work in IE11. not sure what is wrong with that.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the root problem is that some DOM element reference is `undefined` while expected to be defined. Therefore its property `classList` cannot be accessed.

#### How to debug

Most optimal way for debugging will be using Spartacus repo: please clone the spartacus repo, install deps (yarn), and run `yarn start`. Then open it in IE11 and please debug.

The class that looks like a candidate for causing the error might be `PageTemplateDirective`.

I've searched the Spartacus codebase, where `classList` property is accessed. In most cases the DOM element is `body` - which should be always defined. It's not the case only for `PageTemplateDirective` and `ProductIntroComponent` (but the latter one is not displayed on home page, so I think it's not relevant).

Please set the debugger in the methods of `PageTemplateDirective`, to check when the DOM element reference is `undefined` and please investigate further.

[image]

#### Ongoing deprecation of ie11 by Angular

Please note that Angular is planning to deprecate the support of IE11 in ng12 (coming soon) and drop it in ng13 (late 2021). See: https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/41840